# Haskell: Replacing fields in a record based on a variable

Tags: haskell, types

As an example I have a bike, with a front & rear wheel, which both just have an Int to represent the diameter.

```
type Wheel = Int
data Bike = Bike { frontwheel :: Wheel, rearwheel :: Wheel }
    deriving (Show)

mybike = Bike 24 26
```

Now I want to replace a wheel, because I don't like that they're different sizes:

```
replaceFrontWheel :: Bike -> Wheel -> Bike
replaceFrontWheel bike wheel = bike { frontwheel = wheel }

repairedbike = replaceFrontWheel mybike 26
```

That works!

But what if I wanted a function which could either replace the front *or* rear wheel? Both wheels are of the Wheel (Int) type after all, so why not do it with a single function which takes the field as a parameter as well:

```
replaceWheel bike position wheel = bike { position = wheel }

repairedbike = replaceWheel mybike frontwheel 26
```

I do understand why that doesn't work. `position` isn't interpreted as having the value `frontwheel`, but as the (non-existent) field `position` of `Bike`.

Is there a Haskell analogue of (JS) `mybike[position] = 26` or (PHP) `$mybike->$position =  26`?

Is it possible in an elegant way without any external modules?

Otherwise, is it possible using lenses?

Comment: That's pretty much what lenses are all about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens)es are exactly what you need.

```
import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.TH

data Bike = Bike { _frontwheel, _rearwheel :: Wheel }
deriving (Show)
makeLenses ''Bike

replaceWheel :: Bike -> Lens' Bike Wheel -> Wheel -> Bike
replaceWheel bike position wheel = bike & position .~ wheel
```

To be used just like you wanted:

```
repairedbike = replaceWheel mybike frontwheel 26
```

You can weaken the signature a bit:

```
replaceWheel :: Bike -> Setter' Bike Wheel -> Wheel -> Bike
```

which is essentially just a fancy way of saying

```
replaceWheel :: Bike
             -> ((Wheel->Identity Wheel) -> (Bike->Identity Bike))
             -> Wheel
             -> Bike
```

Because `Identity` is just a type-level isomorphism, you might as well omit it, which ends you up with

```
replaceWheel :: Bike -> ((Wheel->Wheel) -> Bike->Bike) -> Wheel -> Bike
replaceWheel bike position wheel = bike & position (const wheel)
                              -- = position (const wheel) bike
```

which can be called thus:

```
data Bike = Bike { _frontwheel, _rearwheel :: Wheel } -- no lenses

frontWheel :: (Wheel -> Wheel) -> Bike -> Bike
frontWheel f (Bike fw rw) = Bike (f fw) rw

repairedbike = replaceWheel mybike frontwheel 26
```

So, indeed you don't strictly speaking need any library for this!

The reasons that it's preferrable to use proper lenses rather than such an ad-hoc approximation include:

- More general. A `Lens'` can be use both to set, get (and traverse) values. This can only awkwardly be expressed without the underlying Rank2-polymorphism that `lens` uses.
- More concise. The types above have a lot of redundancy; lens gives you short synonyms for these accessors.
- Safer. A function `(Wheel -> Wheel) -> Bike -> Bike` could do all kind of rubbish; `lens` requires the lens laws which basically guarantee the lens actually works like a record accessor and nothing more.
- Fast. The combinators in the lens library are written with performance in mind (i.e. support inlining for stream fusion, omitted copying in the state monad etc.).

---

BTW, for functions that “modify something” it's conventional in Haskell to put the argument to be modified last:

```
replaceWheel :: Setter' Bike Wheel -> Wheel -> Bike -> Bike
replaceWheel position wheel = position .~ wheel
```

... or, even shorter,

```
replaceWheel = (.~)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation! After running a `cabal install lens` and adding `{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}` to the top of my file it works perfectly. You also answered another question I had: How to transform fields using functions. Turns out `(%~)` suits my needs!